# how do I change the title of a <div> to the value of another <div> using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div like this

```
<div id="data000">Information</div>

<div id="data001">Click here</div>
```

How do I make the value of the `data000` div be equal to the innetHTML (or value) of the `data001` div?

Thanks!

Comment: Really? -3? What happened to SO...

Comment: @TechBytes the div doesn't have a title, I want to make it the value of the 2nd div

Comment: @TechBytes: Your divs have no titles, and they have `type` attributes which are invalid on divs.

Comment: The title of this question and the content of the question do not match.

Comment: @epascarello they do, read it again

Comment: @epascarello though it may be badly worded and everyone is confused it does match. He wants to `set/change` the `title` attribute of a `div` to the `innerHTML` of the other div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
document.getElementById("data000").title = document.getElementById("data001").innerHTML;
```

will do it.